# goto instruction to jump ahead of variable length array

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    int sz = 10; 
    goto end;
    char bytes[sz];
end:
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error at compilation. I use gcc with C99 standard.

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3:2: error: jump into scope of identifier with variably modified type
test.c:5:1: note: label ‘end’ defined here
test.c:4:7: note: ‘bytes’ declared here
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is forbidden by the standard:

> ```
> C99 standard, paragraph 6.8.6.1
>
> Constraints
>
> [...] A goto statement shall not jump from outside the scope of an identiﬁer having a 
>       variably modiﬁed type to inside the scope of that identiﬁer.
> ```

Your `goto` skips the line that allocates your `bytes` array at runtime. That is not allowed.

You could limit the scope of `bytes` by surrounding it with curly braces, put the allocation before the `goto` and label, or not use `goto` at all.

To put it more plainly, once `bytes` is allocated, you are now "inside" the scope. Before the allocation, you are "outside" the scope. So you can't "jump from outside the scope" to "inside the scope".

Comment: Thanks. once the bytes are allocated, where does the scope end ? But I am trying to understand why the compiler starts a scope for the dynamic array ?

Comment: @sunil: The scope ends at the ending curly brace (`}`).